# Table schema design for user settings

Tags: sql, mysqli

I've got a simple design for user settings, and it works. Basically, there are settings created internally, and each user can have a value for a given setting.

Here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS setting (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    label VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    key VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_setting (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    setting_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    val VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX idx_user_id_and_setting_id (user_id, setting_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_setting_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_setting_setting_id FOREIGN KEY (setting_id) REFERENCES setting (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The query to insert a value in the above schema would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_setting (user_id, setting_id, val)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val = VALUES(val)
```

And to retrieve values for a user, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT setting.*, user_setting.*
FROM setting
INNER JOIN user_setting
    ON user_setting.user_id = ?
    AND user_setting.setting_id = setting.id
```

My problem is that right now the value for each setting must be a `VARCHAR`, and this is not ideal because in some cases a setting may be represented by a checkbox in the UI, or something else that requires a more concrete type. I don't want to use hardcoded values like "true" and "false" in situations like that because it makes the code brittle. I'd much rather check a concrete boolean type.

So this is my proposed solution.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS setting (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    label VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,
    key VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datatype_bool (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    val TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS setting_datatype_bool (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    setting_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    datatype_bool_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX idx_steting_id_and_datatype_bool_id (user_id, datatype_bool_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_setting_datatype_bool_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_setting_datatype_bool_datatype_id FOREIGN KEY (datatype_id) REFERENCES setting_datatype_bool (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_setting (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    setting_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    created_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE INDEX idx_user_id_and_setting_id (user_id, setting_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_setting_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_setting_setting_id FOREIGN KEY (setting_id) REFERENCES setting (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Notice the new `datatype_bool` and `setting_datatype` table. The idea is that a given setting can be assigned a datatype (in this case, a boolean data type -- I could create more tables representing other datatypes), and the value for that setting would be stored in the datatype table.

I haven't actually tested it yet, so I don't have the queries for this variant (though it would be somewhat similar to the first set of queries), but in theory it seems to work.

I was just wondering if anyone has had to do something like this, and/or if anyone has opinions on this design.

Thanks!

Comment: I considered an implementation like yours where settings would be stored dynamically by having one row to describe one setting for one user, but I found it to be more time-efficient and simpler to have one row per user for all their settings, with the settings as column names. Is there a particular reason you need to store your settings dynamically like this?

Comment: No reason at all, really. Pre-optimization, I suppose. Nothing stopping me from doing your proposed solution. I'll probably move in that direction if this turns out to be a headache, as that would require one table in its entirety.

Comment: You're overthinking this; it's a prefs table, not a patient medical history and critical drug prescription system. Being a prefs table it's entirely within your control and you can write your code so it doesn't put bad values in there/handles bad values on the way out by use of defaults. If you're doing this as an academic exercise, great but if this is for a production system just use a simple username/name/value triplet, with varchars. Anything beyond is overkill; incessantly joining tens of tables together just to find out if a checkbox is to be ticked is too much.

Comment: If the concept is complete anathema, consider storing a bit of json per user; type safe in the app when parsed, varchar generation is programmatic so won't go wrong, its human readable enough for a user to edit the database to un-jam something if it's screwed up

Comment: I hear you, I agree it may be overkill. I actually do your proposed solutions for simple user fields, such as username, email, etc., but those are on the user table. These settings are different, specifically to opt int or out for emails and notifications and so on. But again I suppose I could just use the same approach as the fields that are embedded within the user table.

Comment: I don't see where "type" is in your data model.  I tend to think that a separate table for each type is likely to overcomplicate the data model (but that is a matter of opinion).  If you know the settings that you will have, you can store them in a single table, perhaps using a JSON object for future extensions.

Answer (score 0):

instead of bool you can use bit format. you will have to insert 0 or 1 but the Response will be true or false(at least in sql server express, i don`t know exactly in qracle sql). and for UI you can use a drop down menu with true or false based on what user choose you  will insert into DB.